# How do I disable tailcall optimizations in gcc

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I wonder if anyone knows the flag for gcc to disable tailcall optimizations.  Basically in a tailcall optimization, gcc will replace a stack frame when the return value from a called function is passed through (via return) or nothing else happens in the function.

That is, in

```
 void main() {
     foo();
 }

 void foo() {
     bar();
 }
 
 void bar() {
     /* at this point in code, the foo() stack frame no longer exists! */    
 }
```

When foo calls bar, gcc emits code that replaces the stack frame for foo, rather than adding a new stack frame.

My company has a stack unwinder that can print out a stack trace from any point in code.  tailcall optimization makes stack frames disappear, which can confuse the stack trace somewhat.

I am compiling for x86-64 using GCC 4.3.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

GCC manual:

```
   -foptimize-sibling-calls
       Optimize sibling and tail recursive calls.

       Enabled at levels -O2, -O3, -Os.
```

So either compile with `-O0`/`-O1`, or use `-fno-optimize-sibling-calls`.

Answer (score 13):

Untested: **`-fno-optimize-sibling-calls`**

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html