# Can I force the compiler not to optimize tail-recursion?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, tail-recursion

Imagine this code:

```
int foo() {
  return foo();
}
```

The compiler can optimize this. Can I force the compiler to use a new stack frame for foo, instead of using the same stack frame (per case, so disabling optimization completely doesn't count)?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? To exhaust the stack?

Comment: Have you tried disabling all optimization?

Comment: @Matteo Italia it might come in handy some time. I am just wondering if clang and GCC provide this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you actually doing infinite recursion?

Comment: @WTP - i'd be interested to know where you find this to be useful.

Comment: @Luke, I believe he just posted a simpler piece of code. In reality, I'm sure the recursive call is conditional. All that matters for this question is the "return" with the recursive call.

Comment: @Luke: He just wants to "stackoverflow" :D

Comment: I'd have to recommend for(;;);

Comment: The code has UB either way, so I'm not sure how this would be useful...

Comment: @MatteoItalia: While not relevant here, there are some contexts where a jmp may be different from a call followed by a return.  Portable C doesn't allow accessing prior stack frames, but in some particular implementations it can be helpful; sometimes it's important to be able to find the instruction that called a particular routine, and with tail call optimization that won't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable tailcall optimizations in gcc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679435/how-do-i-disable-tailcall-optimizations-in-gcc)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, with `-fno-optimize-sibling-calls` option.

Answer (score 1):

In gcc, try either:

- -O0
- -fno-optimize-sibling-calls